# Why would an init method end with "return self;" instead of "return 0;"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why would I put "return self;" at the end of the class rather than "return 0;"? What is the difference between the two statements?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    //Call the init method implemented by the superclass
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
       //Create two arrays and make the pointers point to them
       questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       answers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

       //Add questions and answers to the arrays
       [questions addObject:@"What is 7 + 7?"];
       [answers addObject:@"14"];

       [questions addObject:@"What is the capital of Vermont?"];
       [answers addObject:@"Montpelier"];

       [questions addObject:@"From what is cognac made?"];
       [answers addObject:@"Grapes"];

   }

   // Return the address of the new object
   return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: By the way: "Why would a class end with `return self;`" - it's not the class that ends with `return self;`. The class ends with `@end`. What you are talking about is a **method.**

Comment: W.r.t. H2CO3's comment: *fix the formatting* - the if block is incorrectly indented.

Comment: As someone new to objective-c, but with some coding experience, I had this exact question. I think the problem with the question is that the author didn't frame their level of familiarity with the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `return 0;` would return a `NULL` pointer. Not something one expects from an initializer that has executed successfully (**exactly** because it's supposed to return the object it has initialized - else you would have lost the object). Initializers are not `main()`.

Comment: Returning 0 from -init indicates a failure in alloc, which is probably beans compared to whatever the hell you did to get alloc to fail.

Comment: @CodaFi: It could also indicate a failure in initialization — hence the famous `if ((self = [super init]))`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically when you want to use an init function, it would be like this

```
MyClass *foo = [[MyClass alloc] initFunction];
```

So if you return 0, the object foo cannot have access to your newly created MyClass.

Comment: `init` methods are usually instance methods, not class methods.

Comment: `So if you return 0, the object foo cannot have access to your newly created MyClass.` Not sure what you mean by this.  I can message `((id)0)` just as easily as I could message a struct with an isa pointer, and even an object.